# Adding tokens to GPT-2 BPE tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I want to add new words to my BPE tokenizer. I know the symbol Ġ means the end of a new token and the majority of tokens in vocabs of pre-trained tokenizers start with Ġ. Assume I want to add the word **Salah** to my tokenizer. I tried to add both **Salah** token and **ĠSalah**:
tokenizer.add_tokens(['Salah', 'ĠSalah']) # they get 50265 and 50266 values respectively.
However, when I tokenize a sentence where **Salah** appears, the tokenizer will never return me the second number (neither when using `.tokenize`nor`.encode`), for instance:
`tokenizer.tokenize('I love Salah and salad')` returns `['I', 'Ġlove', 'Salah', 'Ġand', 'Ġsalad']`.
The question is: should I use the symbol `Ġ` when adding new tokens or the tokenizer does it itself? Or, probably, it must be specified manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware that you have to pretrain the model if you want to add custom tokens?

Comment: @dennlinger sure, but to make the fine-tuning better I need to add some popular tokens of the target dataset.